# Adding check in .equals() for different value type

Tags: java, equals

I have a class with a few fields, one of which is an `int`, and 2 are `long`. What I'm thinking of doing is adding in a check in `equals()` so if an `Integer` object is passed in, it will compare the `int` field, and if the same return `true`. Likewise, if `Long` is passed in, if it is between the 2 `long` fields, it will return `true`.

So, if I add several of these objects to a `List` or `Set`, I can then do a `get()` and have it automatically give me the first object that matches. My thought is if I do this, then I simply make the `get()` call, and then I'll have it, instead of having to have an extra loop & checks.

Is this a good idea or bad idea compared to simply iterating over all of the objects and doing the comparisons that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do this.

The `equals()` method has [a well-defined contract,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and your proposed implementation violates it. For example, it won't be *symmetric*; if `x` is your object and `y` is an `Integer`, `y.equals(x)` will be false even when `x.equals(y)` is true. Breaking these rules will confuse anyone who has to work with your code—even yourself, in the future, when you are more accustomed to using this method correctly.

Your use cases sound like they could be satisfied with a [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html), where keys are integers, and values are instances of your class.

Comment: Yea, as I was putting this together, I was thinking it was a less and less of a good idea/clever hack and more of a very dangerous idea. I was still interested in hearing everyone's opinion on the subject.

Comment: @Drizzt321 That makes sense. Let me know if you'd like more information about using a `NavigableMap`.

Comment: Thanks erickson, but I think I'll just stick with a foreach or iterator for this, it suits the possible data better.

Comment: This answer is correct.  But note that equals() implementations are allowed to return `true` for objects of different types (as long as the contract isn't broken).  But then it's best for these types to have a common interface that enforces this behaviour in the contract.  An example is the List interface: an ArrayList and LinkedList are equal if they contain the same objects.

Answer (score 1):

The performance will be the same but the code will be obfuscated. A different developer (or yourself in a couple of month) will just expect `equals()` to check if an object is *equal*.

I would go for a more explicit solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your equals method should have one concrete implementation without depending on the type of Object being passed, read the equals contract [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) as anyone reading your code or javadoc will expect it to be as per the contract.

For such cases you can write your own custom `Comparator` and use it to search your objects in collection.

Or have separate equals method like `checkIntEquality` and `checkLongEquality` and call them as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

That only makes sense if the semantics of the object follow the same logic.

If the different types represent different values, with different meanings, this type of overloading generates confusion.

It also sounds like the "equals" for longs isn't even an equals, which is worse.

Encapsulating the behavior in the object is fine, but should be named sensibly.